# File upload in asp.net with progress bar and pause and resume functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to upload file on the server with pause and resume capability 
and if possible I want design something which is used in following url:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/manualupload/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: To have a progress bar/pause ability for file upload means that you need to use socket programming instead, I mean that you should handle each packet of data you received at server and whole amount of packets to finish uploading file, So I can say your question is broad to have an answer here. ;).

Comment: Possible related question: [Sending and receiving data over a network using TcpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3609280/4519059) ;).

Comment: Is there a reason you want to write it instead of using http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/manualupload/defaultcs.aspx itself?